# Cannot boot to BIOS(Tried everything, minus pulling hardware)

Tags: motherboard, bios

Can't boot to BIOS, my version of BIOS is American Megatrends Inc. V1.3, 11/7/2011. I've done about everything I could think of except for removing the  RAM/Processer/MOBO out of the computer.

- Exchanged keyboards
- Pressed all combinations the would typically lead to BIOS
- Mashed a whole lot of keys trying to get a keyboard error
- Removed the hard drive containing the operating system and plugging in a USB with bootable media on it
- Removed and reseated the CMOS battery

I'm not even seeing the typical motherboard/BIOS screen come up. Just a blank screen with a solid cursor in the top left and text that reads "B2" in the bottom right. It stays on that screen for a good minute or two then moves on to a completely blank screen on my second monitor.

Operating system boots fine. Currently trying to install Windows 10 onto a formatted Samsung 850 EVO SSD. (I had windows installed onto the SSD up until a few days ago and ran into some pretty mind-boggling issues so I decided on a format and a fresh install)

I built this system about 5 years ago, still using the same motherboard and processor I started with.

SPECS:

> - Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
> - AMD Phenom II X4 960T
> - 8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 666MHz (9-9-9-24)
> - MSI 970A-G45 (MS-7693)
> - 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 (EVGA)
> - 931GB Seagate ST1000DM003-9YN162 ATA Device (SATA)

Comment: ALSO - I was thinking of maybe flashing the BIOS. Wasn't sure if that might fix the issue, but on the American Megatrends site I have no idea which piece of software I need to install to do that.


I'm starting to think this is an issue with the motherboard, but everything else works fine.


There has to be a simple solution. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

`B2` sounds like a BIOS "POST" code - the BIOS writes values to 0x80 and they can be read by a POST card, and some BIOSes may display such a code on a screen when encountering an error.

I found a site that lists POST codes for various BIOSes and boards - http://www.postcodemaster.com/inteldxxx.shtml - and on that page in particular there is this:

> B2 Detecting presence of a fixed media (IDE hard drive detection etc.)

Perhaps your BIOS doesn't like your SSD for some reason.  I recently tried getting an SSD working on an old Alienware laptop from 2004 - had an issue where the BIOS was unresponsive and I troubleshooted it down to an issue with the partition table.

So maybe it could be that, or something else with the SSD.  Perhaps a newer BIOS gets along better with SSDs.  You might try backing up your data from that SSD and updating its firmware.  As a last resort consider getting an add-in PCIe card for your SSD and maybe then there will be less issues.

Comment: AHAH, a POST code, I assumed it was something along those lines, but couldn't pull up the information, I appreciate you finding it for me!


Unfortunately, I don't think the post code is related, it hangs on that screen forever whether I have a drive in that can boot to the operating system or not. Currently I have no drives in and it still hangs on that screen for a few minutes.

Comment: Also, If i put nothing but the bootable media in, that's what boots up. So I'm wondering if I can put the Windows 10 USB Media in, let that boot up, and then plug the SSD in and install Windows. Guess I'll find out.